# getting Init:ErrImagePull while installing nvidia plugin in GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nvidia

I am unable to install Nvidia GPU plugin in GKE. I followed this link https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#installing_drivers to install. While describing the pod I'm getting

```
Failed to pull image "cos-nvidia-installer:fixed": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/cos-nvidia-installer:fixed": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/cos-nvidia-installer:fixed": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ErrImagePull condition means that the node is unable to pull the container image from the container image registry. Some potential causes of this issue:

- The container is unavailable or inaccessible from the node
- The container image does not exists in the registry
- The container image specified in the deployment manifest is incorrect

The problem with creating a centralized **cos-gpu-installer:fixed**, is that we won't be able to tie the driver version down to the OS version. They go through relevant qualification and testing before they are preloaded. So on a specific GKE version, you always get the same driver version. This makes it challenging to have a single tag that the node could pull from a registry.

The pre-loaded installer image **"cos-nvidia-installer:fixed"** had some changes to only use the default driver version for a certain cos version.

One workaround is to set the driver version with another container image in the configuration file i.e specify the full image version in the daemonset `(e.g. gcr.io/cos-cloud/cos-gpu-installer@sha256:8d86a652759f80595cafed7d3dcde3dc53f57f9bc1e33b27bc3cfa7afea8d483)`, you can also set container image of latest version and try. Since this version refers to the same image that's preloaded, the image pull should be very fast.

**Try changing these fields in the [configuration file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/cos/daemonset-preloaded.yaml):**

```
  initContainers:
     - image: gcr.io/cos-cloud/cos-gpu-installer@sha256:8d86a652759f80595cafed7d3dcde3dc53f57f9bc1e33b27bc3cfa7afea8d483
       name: nvidia-driver-installer
```

**And**

```
    env:
      - name: NVIDIA_INSTALL_DIR_HOST
        value: /home/kubernetes/bin/nvidia
      - name: NVIDIA_INSTALL_DIR_CONTAINER
        value: /usr/local/nvidia
      - name: VULKAN_ICD_DIR_HOST
        value: /home/kubernetes/bin/nvidia/vulkan/icd.d
      - name: VULKAN_ICD_DIR_CONTAINER
        value: /etc/vulkan/icd.d
      - name: ROOT_MOUNT_DIR
        value: /root
      - name: NVIDIA_DRIVER_VERSION
        value: "450.51.06"
    volumeMounts:
```